# Search/Filter Freeform submissions by field value

Tags: search, plugin-freeform, freeform

I need to be able to get a count (in the frontend) of the number of submissions that have a field with a specific value. I don't need the submitted data of the submissions, just the count of submissions whose data matches a specified value.

This code returns the total number of submissions:

```
{% set submissionCount = craft.freeform.submissions({
    form: 'myAmazingForm'
}).count %}
```

I tried using the native Craft search parameter, but it returns zero:

```
{% set submissionCount = craft.freeform.submissions({
    form: 'myAmazingForm'
}).search('fieldWithValue:123').count %}
```

And yes, there *are* submissions that would match that.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the workaround I've resorted to using in the meantime.

```
{# Initiate the hash in which we'll store matching submissions. #}
{% set matchingSubmissions = [] %}

{#
    Loop through all submissions, checking if the specified field
    matches the desired value.
#}
{% for submission in submissions if submission.fieldWithValue == '123' %}

    {# If the field matches, add it to the hash #}
    {% set matchingSubmissions = matchingSubmissions|merge([submission.fieldWithValue]) %}

{% endfor %}

{# Count the size of the resulting hash and save it. #}
{% set submissionCount = matchingSubmissions|length %}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not work, but you can try it like so:

```
{% set submissionCount = craft.freeform.submissions({
    form: 'myAmazingForm',
    fieldWithValue: '123',
}).count() %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this currently isn't possible. However, we've added it to the feature requests list and will revisit adding this in the not-too-distant future. :)

Comment: Drat! I'm converting an EE site that uses that Freeform feature and had expected to be able to do the same things. :-/

Comment: @solspace I'm just curious... It took me only a few minutes to create that feature with a custom function and a search via Yii Records, why don't you present a workaround even just for this special use case - instead of saying not possible currently?

Comment: I'd love to see a temporary workaround for this...?

Comment: Is this possible right now? @Solspace

Comment: An upcoming version will include this (late May 2019)