# Freeform plugin unique submission amount

Tags: plugin-freeform, freeform

I'm needing to get the unique entry submission amount for a value.

**Example:**
Item1, Item2, Item1, Item3, Item1

**Would return:**
3

I was able to use the workaround here [Search/Filter Freeform submissions by field value](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23277/search-filter-freeform-submissions-by-field-value) to get the specific submission amount but only wanting to know the number of unique submission values.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a Craft 2 plugin that exposes PHP's [array_unique](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) method to Twig.

So to continue on the example you linked to, it would be something like this with that plugin installed:

```
{# Initiate the hash in which we'll store matching submissions. #}
{% set matchingSubmissions = [] %}

{#
    Loop through all submissions, checking if the specified field
    matches the desired value.
#}
{% for submission in submissions if submission.fieldWithValue == '123' %}

    {# If the field matches, add it to the hash #}
    {% set matchingSubmissions = matchingSubmissions|merge([submission.fieldWithValue]) %}

{% endfor %}

{# Count the size of the resulting hash and save it. #}
{% set totalUniques = matchingSubmissions|unique|length %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also add `andWhere` to your query. Look to the table 'freeform_fields' for the field who you want to use for the query end remember the id of the field. In the table 'freeform_submissions' look to the field names an look to field_[rememberd_id]

field__21 is in my case a hidden field for an entryId to show all submissions related to an entry.

for example:

```
{% set submissions = craft.freeform.submissions({
    form: 'formName',
    status: ["open"],
}).andWhere('field_21 =' ~ entry.id) %}
```